# ggmosaic: how to remove the thin line when the count of a factor levels is 0

Tags: r, ggplot2, mosaic-plot

I've been trying to make a Mosaic / Marimekko plot using ggmosaic, but would wish to remove [the thin line marking a hspine with the count of 0 (second column)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CADh5.png) .

Can this be done in ggmosaic? I couldn't find how in the vignette / help files. A reproducible example below.

```
library(ggmosaic)    

happy2 <- happy
happy2$marital <- 
  ifelse(happy2$marital == "never married" & happy2$happy == "not too happy",
       NA, happy2$marital)

ggplot(happy2) + 
  geom_mosaic(aes(x = product(happy, marital), fill = happy))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know whether or not it could be adjusted in ggmosaic, but it turned out this plot can be done very easily with ggplot

```
happy2 <- happy
happy2$marital <- 
  ifelse(happy2$marital == "never married" & happy2$happy == "not too happy",
       NA, happy2$marital)

ggplot(happy2) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x = marital, fill = happy), colour = "black", 
               width = 1, stat = "count", position = "fill") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0))
```